# Deploying business network definition Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I try to deploy the business network with `composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString -A admin -S` but I get the error message: `Error: Error trying deploy. Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err MSP Org1MSP is unknown`

My versions are:

**Docker**

```
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:40:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:45:38 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

**Node**

```
v6.11.4
```

**npm**

```
5.5.1
```

It ´s supposed following this [issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1510) that I must update Docker but it is updated to the last version.

I am using Mac OS 10.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates membership service provider for org1 is unknown. Try to clean everything using the below commands and try again.

docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm -f

docker images -aq | xargs docker rmi -f

Note:The following commands will delete any running containers and delete all downloaded images,be careful if you're using other Docker images on your machine.